# Just like/just as + complete statement

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Example sentence:

> You have no reason to come out of your apartment, just *like/as* I
> have no reason to go in.

Should it be *like* or *as*? And why?

Comment: We use *just as* when comparing two situations. *Just like* would be more appropriate when comparing the physical appearance of two things.

Comment: *Just like* sounds less formal than *just as*, but is perfectly understandable (at least to this US English speaker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, because there is a verb after like/as (go in), you should use the conjunction **as**:

> You have no reason to come out your apartment, just as I have no reason to go in.

**Like** is typically used to compare two things. For example:

> Your apartment looks like my brother's apartment.

That said, in spoken American English, **like** has become a very common informal  choice, even though it's technically incorrect. What that means is you are very likely to hear people use **like** when speaking, but you will probably see **as** used in written English since it is the correct choice.